# Displaying results of image filters

Tags: ros, gui, images

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like a way to display images and results of several image filters and data extracted from images in a interactive GUI. The GUI would need to display at least 6 panels, some of which would be 2 or 3 dimensional plots, and then a couple panels to show results of image filters. One of the plots should also be interactive, allowing for a data point selection tool.

Finally, I would want displaying this data to be integrated with ROS. For example, one of the panels should show the result of listening to a topic that is publishing sensor_msgs/Image. Other panels that show filtered images should show the data being published by my ROS nodes or the results of calling my ROS services.

I'm a little new to python, C++, and ROS, so I apologize for my ignorance. Is there a tool or set of tools that can help me do this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53477/displaying-results-of-image-filters/) by [robzz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3420/robzz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 328 on 2013-01-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can do all the image processing with ROS using [CV_Bridge](http://www.ros.org/wiki/cv_bridge/Tutorials/UsingCvBridgeToConvertBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImages), and [rxplot](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rxplot) for the graphs.

---

Originally posted by [jd](https://answers.ros.org/users/2939/jd/) with karma: 62 on 2013-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [facesad](https://answers.ros.org/users/6385/facesad/) on 2013-09-04**:
of course you can find a lot of online image sdk that is able to display image the data and the   [image filters vb.net](http://www.rasteredge.com/how-to/vb-net-imaging/image-processing-filter/). change a few lines then they will be able to integrate with ROS. "image filters vb.net. change a few lines then they will be able to integrate with ROS.